# How to add delay

Tags: arrays, swift, uikit, delay

I am creating a simple card matching game in swift. What I want to do it to add a 5 second delay to my code, so when 2 cards are clicked, there will be a 5 second delay before it turns back around on its own, without having to click on it again. Beneath is my current code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import SwiftUI

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: - IBOutlets
    
    @IBOutlet weak var c0: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var c1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var c2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var c3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var c4: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var c5: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var c6: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var c7: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var c8: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var c9: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var c10: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var c11: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfPairsLabel: UILabel!
    
    
    // MARK: - Variables and Constants
    
    var buttonsArray = [UIButton]()
    var answers = [Int]()
    var faceDown = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]
    var matchedCards = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
    var randCard = -1
    var cardDrawn  = -1
    var numFaceUp = 0
    var disabledCards = false
    var numberOfPairs = 0
    var player: AVAudioPlayer!
    var timeRemaining = 30
    var timer = Timer() //variable type is timer
    
    
    @objc func countDown() {
        if timeRemaining > 0 {
            timeRemaining -= 1
            timerLabel.text = String(timeRemaining)
        } else {
            GameOver()
            timerLabel.text = String(timeRemaining)
                  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                  let secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "gameOverPopUp") as! SecondViewController
                  self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
        
    
 // end countDown function
    
    
    func GameOver() {
        timer.invalidate()
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "popUpView", sender: self)
    }
    
    
    
    @IBAction func cardClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        cardDrawn = Int(sender.restorationIdentifier!)!
        
        //if card is currently facedown, then show card number that matches drawn card
        
        if (faceDown[cardDrawn] == true){
            buttonsArray[cardDrawn].setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: String(answers[cardDrawn])), for: .normal)
            faceDown[cardDrawn] = false
            
        }
        //if card is face-up then show back of the card
        else{
            buttonsArray[cardDrawn].setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "back"), for: .normal)
            faceDown[cardDrawn] = true
        }
        
        //check how many cards are currently faced up
        numFaceUp = faceDown.filter({$0 == false}).count
        print(numFaceUp)
        if numFaceUp == 2{
            disabledCards = true
            
            // Delay the card turning back around
                
        }
      
        //Checking how many cards are currently faced up
        numFaceUp = faceDown.filter({$0 == false}).count
        
        
      //  if 2 cards are face-up then disable all other cards untill they are bith face down again or a match is found.
      if disabledCards == true {
      var flippedCardFound = false
            var cardPos1 = -1
            var cardPos2 = -1
            
            
            if numFaceUp == 2{
                //is card at i is facedown then disable it.
                for i in 0...11{
                    if (faceDown[i] == true)
                    {
                        buttonsArray[i].isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                    }
                    
                    //if card is face up record its position
                    if (faceDown[i] == false && flippedCardFound == false){
                        cardPos1 = i
                        flippedCardFound = true
                    }
                    //if te second card is face up record its position
                    else if (faceDown[i] == false && flippedCardFound == true){
                        cardPos2 = i
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if ((cardPos2 != -1) && (answers[cardPos1]==answers[cardPos2])){
                matchedCards[cardPos1] = true
                matchedCards[cardPos2] = true
                buttonsArray[cardPos1].isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                buttonsArray[cardPos2].isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                numFaceUp = 0
                
                if (matchedCards.filter({ $0 == true}).count) == 12{
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "You did it!", message: "Congradulations!", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default,handler: nil))
                
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    
                }
            }
        }
        

        
    
        
        //if number of face-up cards is back to 0 then reenable unmatched cards.
        if numFaceUp == 0 {
            disabledCards = false
            faceDown = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]
            for i in 0...11{
                if matchedCards[i] == false{
                    buttonsArray[i].isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                }
            }
        }
        
        if timeRemaining == 0 {
            
            GameOver()
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func newGameAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        newGame()
    }
    
    func runTimer() {
           timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(countDown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
       }

    
    
    func newGame (){
        
        
        timer.invalidate()
        
        timerLabel.text = "30"
        
        timeRemaining = 30
        
        
        disabledCards = false
        numFaceUp = 0
        faceDown = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]
        matchedCards = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
        //this loop sets the background of each button to "back and enables each button.
        for i in 0...11{
            buttonsArray[i].isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            buttonsArray[i].setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "back"), for: .normal)
        }
        //removes all answers from answers array so that new ones can be added at the start of each game
        answers.removeAll()
        
        //this array will be used to create the array for the random card draw
        //each number is in there twice to represent the same card twice
        var nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        
        //this loop randomely selects a number form the nums array and then appends that number to the next
        //available positions in the answers array. That number is then removed from the nums array so that it cannot be used twice
        
        for i in 0...11{
            let randCard = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(nums.count)))
            answers.append(nums[randCard])
            //[2, 1, 4]
            nums.remove(at: randCard)
            //[0, 1, 3, 5, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        }
        
        print(answers)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        buttonsArray = [c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11]
        newGame()
        playSound()
        runTimer()
    }
    
    //if {
    //numberOfPairs = numberOfPairs + 1
    //numberOfPairsLabel.text = (numberOfPairs)
    //}
    
    // MARK: - IBActions and Functions
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    
    
    func playSound() {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Audio.mp3", withExtension: nil)
        player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
        player!.play()
    }
    
    //    func stopSound() {
    //        player?.stop()
    //        stopButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "speaker.fill"), for: .normal)
    //    }
    
    //    }
    
    //    @IBAction func stopButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    //    }
    //    @IBOutlet weak var stopButton: UIButton!
    
    
    //stopButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "speaker.slash.fill"), for: .normal)
    
}
```

Comment: A simple way of giving a delay is use of `DispatchQueue`.  Ask a search engine about DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GCD and write the following:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
    // Turn cards back
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably **don't** want to use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` ...

Assuming the user has tapped two non-matching cards, and you allow *another* tap on one of those cards to "flip them back over," you don't want a 5-second delay to kick in.

Instead, create another timer:

```
var flipBackTimer: Timer!
```

So, assuming we have a func like this:

```
@objc func autoFlipBack() {
    // whatever code you're using to
    // turn the mis-match cards back over
}
```

When the second non-matching card has been shown, start *that* timer.

```
flipBackTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.autoFlipBack), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

If the user then taps the mis-matched card to "manually" turn them over, invalidate that timer:

```
if let t = flipBackTimer {
    t.invalidate()
}
```